# Download VS 2010 solution from internet > can't build > not adequate permissions windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I think I need to turn off a security layer in VS2010 somehow.

Error   1   The command "esriRegasm.exe "C:\Users\Patrick\Downloads\MyDynamicLayer\CSharp\bin\Debug\MyDynamicLayer.dll" /p:Engine /s" exited with code -1.  C:\Users\Patrick\Downloads\MyDynamicLayer\CSharp\MyDynamicLayer2010.csproj  126 5   MyDynamicLayer2010

I have admin permission on my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to run CMD.exe as Admin -> its a right click option